# Mongo Db Query Json Inside Json Filter

Tags: mongodb

There is an mongo table entity.

```
     @Document(collection = "A")
        public class A {
        private int id;
        private List<Student> allstud;
        //setter and getter
        }

      public class Student {
        private int id;
private String name
        private DateTime  JoinDate;
        //setter and getter
        }
```

Joining dates can any date in a year;
 the query so that can get 8 month joining student.

```
db.A.find({
    "allstud.JoinDate": {
        "$gte": ISODate("2018-08-01T00:00:00.000+00:00"),
        "$lte": ISODate("2018-08-29T00:00:00.000+00:00")
    }
});
```

But above query giving wrong List. All dates are coming.

Comment: help me out i am getting stuck in it.

Answer (score 0):

```
   db.A.aggregate([
    { $unwind :'$allstud'},
    { $match : {
        "allstud.joinDate": { $gte:ISODate("2018-08-05T00:00:00.000+00:00"), $lte: ISODate("2018-08-09T00:00:00.000+00:00") }
    }}
    ]);
```

By this query i got the correct answer.But how can we convert into this to java Query